# Add properties to an entity hook_schema_alter

Tags: 7, entities

I need to implement a custom module that adds fields and properties to an entity defined in another module. I felt the best way to do this was using hook_schema_alter and hook_update_n to achieve the data structure updates. However, I do not see these new fields on my entity. Is there another step to take to attach these to the entity via code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the third-party [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module, you can:

- Implement [hook_schema_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7).
- Use something like [db_add_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_field/7) to actually make the change to the DB in YOURMODULE_install() or updateN(). `hook_schema_alter()` does not actually create the field in the database. It just tells other modules at the code level that the field exists in the schema.
- Implement [hook_entity_property_info_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info_alter/7). This tells the Entity API module that this field exists as a property of some entity, where it lives in the database table, and how to access it.

  - Clear the cache to have the new properties showing up.

An example property in the $info array is basically the following one:

```
  $properties['survey_count_to_complete'] = array(
    'label' => t('Number of Surveys to Complete'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'description' => 'When a student logs in the system derives how many surveys they must complete. We store this value to make business logic easier.',
    // This is the schema field you made.
    'schema field' => 'survey_count_to_complete',
    'getter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_get',
    'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
  );
```

Comment: where to call db_add_field() so that it is called only once?

Comment: in either hook_install() for a module during install. Or, hook_update_n(). You can also check if a db column exists in any script before calling db_add_field with https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_field_exists/7 ... so the code doesn't have to run once persay.

Comment: thx! that was helpful .. i can now add properties to the node entity type :)

Comment: `hook_schema_alter()` DOES create/change the schema in the database. It is a wrong information (maybe it was correct back then, but not anymore).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example which implements [`hook_schema_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7):

```
/*
 * Implements hook_schema_alter().
 */
function mymodule_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['tablename']['fields']['fieldname'] = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'default' => null
  );
}

/*
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function mymodule_install() {
  if (!db_field_exists('tablename', 'fieldname')) {
    $schema = drupal_get_schema('tablename');
    db_add_field('tablename', 'status', $schema['fields']['fieldname']);
  }
}

/*
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  if (db_field_exists('tablename', 'fieldname')) {
    $schema = drupal_get_schema('tablename');
    db_drop_field('tablename', 'fieldname');
  }
}
```

Where `mymodule` is your module name, `tablename` your table name and `fieldname` is your field name.