# Updating Entity Properties with hook_update_N()

Tags: entities, updating

I have a custom module which defines a custom entity. Now I would like to add a new field to this entity without reinstalling my module. I tried it with the `hook_update_N()` function:

```
/**
 * Description
 */
function MY_MODULE_update_7100() {
  $spec = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'description' => 'Description',
    'not null' => FALSE,
  );
  db_add_field('my_table', 'my_new_field', $spec);
}
```

in my Module, I updated my existing `hook_entity_property_info_alter` to add the definition for this field:

```
function MY_MODULE_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $props = &$info['my_entity']['properties'];
  // snip
  $props['my_new_field'] = array(
    'label' => t('My Label'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'description' => t('My Description'),
    'schema field' => 'my_new_field',
  );
  // snap
}
```

After updating, I can still create and update the entity, but sadly not my new Field which I created.

What did I wrong?

I looked for an example in the commerce module. But the module is using `drupal_write_record` instead of `entity_save`.

PS: I already saw [this issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25396/add-properties-to-an-entity-hook-schema-alter) but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had this problem myself in the past and almost pulled all my hair out! :)

It turned out that I had forgotten to update my hook_schema declaration within the .install file of my module, and include the definition of the new database field for my entity table.

Adding in the definition *should* make the new field available to you.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. If I update my `hook_schema()` function, I have to reinstall the module and loose all my entries to update my table.
The new Field for the database was added successfully after updating. But it seems to be that the entity does not understand that there is a new Field to fill in the Table.

Comment: @moertle you just need to add the new field to your hook_schema definition. It's referred to when updating your entity.

Comment: Now it works! Both, Thank you very much, you saved my day! Heroes! :)

Comment: no problem! :) I also just recently started working with custom entitites and know how confusing it can initially be.

Comment: ohh!!! you are just awesome.......
after 1 day of search i just found this solution +1

Comment: no problem glad I could help out